# Can't login into Fedora 14 (XFCE) desktop. For the second time

Tags: troubleshooting, xfce, login-screen, fedora-14

I'm experiencing a problem with my Fedora 14 XFCE spin, which doesn't seem to let me pass the login screen: I enter my password for my user record, authentication passes (no 'Authentication Failure' message, which was when I tried to login as 'root' without root login enabled), and the screen becomes black (command line) for a couple of seconds and (voila!) my login screen emerges again.

I did nothing to cause that, it just suddenly logged me out when I was editing window manager settings via XFCE's built-in GUI utility (choosing window decorations style, from the listbox on the left)

For the first time, I had to boot from live CD and do a fresh install, but I don't really want to do that again.

Is there some way to repair this (maybe login via command line and reset window manager settings, I don't know really)?

Comment: The same thing just now after 2-3 reboots :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting your XFCE configuration:

```
mv ~/.config/xfce4 ~/xfce-config-backup
rm -r ~/.cache
```

If that doesn't work, try starting XFCE from the command line and see if it displays any errors:

```
startxfce4
```

Comment: Thx, I'll try it today, when I'm at home :) I Hope I didn't forget the correct keystroke for logging into the command line - Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F6 actually

Comment: I've repaired xfwm with the help of you advice. It was that 'Wildbush' xfwm4 theme that caused the crash. All I needed is to login via command line, then navigate to ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml and set the theme property to something else. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting your user's password?

Login as root and use one of the nice gui tools if available in xfce or type the following into a terminal:

```
passwd username
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as root. Your /tmp directory may have the wrong permissions:

```
chmod a+rwx /tmp
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did to make my command look better? I'm not sure what the tags are here.