# Cannot login fresh install Linux Mint XFCE

Tags: installation, login, linux-mint

After I install and am taken to login for the first time (login screen with clouds), I have tried clicking my username from the list, then typed the password. It comes back with a message with username or password being incorrect. I have also tried just typing my username and password with equal results. What is causing this. No one else seems to have had this problem.

On a side note, with Manjaro XFCE, the same thing happens. I assume it is tied into the display manager. Would love to hear from someone knowledgeable about this.

Comment: well if xfce is causing the problem why not changing it, there's no shortage of desktop environments kde or cinnamon, anyway as for you question take a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1907742 and http://superuser.com/questions/246872/cant-login-into-fedora-14-xfce-desktop-for-the-second-time and http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=148184

Comment: When I have tried other variants of Mint, including those you mentioned, the same thing occurs.

Comment: I should add that both Mint and Manjaro are using the exact same display manager. I am confident enough to state that it has nothing to do with the DE.

Comment: maybe you should change the title of your question, if you think it has nothing to do with xfce, and ask about display manager, also could you try to use other distro that uses another display manager, if you believe the display manager has something to do with your issue, then trying another display manager should solve it

Comment: As it happens, I WANT to use Manjaro and Mint. I opted to use Mint in the title, because it has a larger fan base. I opted to use XFCE in the title because it is a popular DE and I also want to use it. So, I am hitting the ball back into your court for actual help if you know how to resolve the situation.

Comment: fine, could you open a terminal? if you are confident that it's the display manager, you could change it http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860704 but as far as i personally know, it's not recommended to do so, probably I'm wrong

Comment: one small note, you can't always use what you want to use, especially when it comes to linux, i'd love to use linux mint cinnamon, but can't coz it doesn't work unless i use `nonmodeset`, if i do so, cinammon will go to fallback mode and won't work, I'd love to use Fuduntu, but nomodeset will break the desktop, so i opted to use crunchbang coz its a lightweight and works good on my graphic card, I'd love to get sleep mode to work on my hp, but hp didn't create sleep mode drivers yet for my debian and my laptop, sometimes you have to choose what will work for your pc or change it...

Comment: I had exactly this problem and I applied the answer that was exactly the solution. +1 for the question and +1 for the answer. If there are alternative ways to formulate it, create duplicates! Duplicates can be important since search engines can't really understand what you mean when you search, or what the OP in a question means or what the people answering a question means. Search engines don't really understand language, so creating awkwardly general questions isn't really going to help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from 2013. I assume Terence found his answer, or worked around this, but I JUST fresh installed LM Xfce 18.2 and had the same issue! Found kind of the answer in a different LM forum, but figured it out on my own. So, I post this here in case some one else encounters the same problem, presently.

At first login, after fresh install, if your user name and password won't work, type mint as the user name, and leave the password blank. On my machine, it appeared to do something, and then went back to the login fields again. I tried my user name and password, told me it was wrong again. Typed mint as user, and left the password blank, again, and SUCCESS! I was on the desktop and had the message that the installation had finished. I rebooted, and when the login screen came up, MY user name was already there, and I typed my password. All is well!